# I don't understand how to pass variables to function in my code(Java)

Tags: java, variables

I'm relatively new to programming so be patient with me. I can't figure out how to pass the variables p12c, p13c etc. to the method `findWinner`. I ran into this problem quite often, so if you could provide some help I will appreciate it. Also, any tips on how to simplify any code is welcome too. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StarterPoker {             
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Welcome to Starter Poker!\n\n" +
                    "To play, two players will be dealt\n"+
                    "five cards per hand and the hand with\n"+
                    "the highest cards will win. Then you\n"+
                    "will be prompted to continue or quit.\n");
            dealHand();
            findWinner();
        }
        while(playAgain()=='Y');        
    }

    public static void dealHand()
    {
         int p12c=0, p13c=0, p14c=0, p15c=0, p16c=0, p17c=0, p18c=0, p19c=0, p1tc=0, p1jc=0, p1qc=0, p1kc=0, p1ac=0;
         int p22c=0, p23c=0, p24c=0, p25c=0, p26c=0, p27c=0, p28c=0, p29c=0, p2tc=0, p2jc=0, p2qc=0, p2kc=0, p2ac=0;
         int [][] deck        = new int[13][4];
         int [][] player1hand = new int[5][2];
         int [][] player2hand = new int[5][2];  

         //the p1 = player1, then it has each card value, followed by c for count, for example: p12c = player1 2s count.

         String[] suits = {"Spades","Diamonds","Hearts","Clubs"};
         String[] cards = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"};

         Random randGen = new Random();
         do
         {
             String hand1 = "";
             //dealing hand 1
             for(int dex = 0; dex < player1hand.length; dex++)
             {                  
                 boolean goodCard = false;
                 while(!goodCard)
                 {
                     int suit = randGen.nextInt(4);
                     int card = randGen.nextInt(13);

                     if( deck[card][suit] == 0)
                     {
                         goodCard = true;
                         deck[card][suit] = 1;
                         player1hand[dex][0] = suit;
                         player1hand[dex][1] = card;
                         hand1 += "\n     "+cards[card]+" of "+suits[suit]+"";  
                         if(card == 0) p12c=p12c+1;
                         if(card == 1) p13c=p13c+1;
                         if(card == 2) p14c=p14c+1;
                         if(card == 3) p15c=p15c+1;
                         if(card == 4) p16c=p16c+1;
                         if(card == 5) p17c=p17c+1;
                         if(card == 6) p18c=p18c+1;
                         if(card == 7) p19c=p19c+1;
                         if(card == 8) p1tc=p1tc+1;
                         if(card == 9) p1jc=p1jc+1;
                         if(card == 10) p1qc=p1qc+1;
                         if(card == 11) p1kc=p1kc+1;
                         if(card == 12) p1ac=p1ac+1;                            
                     }
                 }
             }  
             String hand2 = "";
             //dealing hand 1
             for(int dex = 0; dex < player2hand.length; dex++)
             {
                 boolean goodCard = false;
                 while(!goodCard)
                 {
                     int suit = randGen.nextInt(4);
                     int card = randGen.nextInt(13);

                     if( deck[card][suit] == 0)
                     {
                         goodCard = true;
                         deck[card][suit] = 1;
                         player2hand[dex][0] = suit;
                         player2hand[dex][1] = card;
                         hand2 += "\n     "+cards[card]+" of "+suits[suit]+"";                              
                         if(card == 0) p22c=p22c+1;
                         if(card == 1) p23c=p23c+1;
                         if(card == 2) p24c=p24c+1;
                         if(card == 3) p25c=p25c+1;
                         if(card == 4) p26c=p26c+1;
                         if(card == 5) p27c=p27c+1;
                         if(card == 6) p28c=p28c+1;
                         if(card == 7) p29c=p29c+1;
                         if(card == 8) p2tc=p2tc+1;
                         if(card == 9) p2jc=p2jc+1;
                         if(card == 10) p2qc=p2qc+1;
                         if(card == 11) p2kc=p2kc+1;
                         if(card == 12) p2ac=p2ac+1;
                     }
                 }
             }                  
             System.out.print("\nDo you want to deal two hands?\nenter 'Y' to continue or anything else to quit: ");        
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             char cont = input.next().charAt(0);
             if(cont != 'Y')
             {
                 System.out.println("Program terminated!");
                 System.exit(0);
             }
             System.out.printf("Player 1's hand is %s\n", hand1);
             System.out.printf("Player 2's hand is %s\n", hand2);       
         } while(true);
    }  

    public static void findWinner()
    {
        int p1s = 0, p2s = 0;
        int p1p = 0, p2p = 0;
        int p1t = 0, p2t = 0;
        int p1f = 0, p2f = 0;

        if (p12c > 0)
        {
            if(p12c >1)
            {
                if(p12c > 2)
                {
                    if(p12c > 3)
                    {
                        p1f = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p1t = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    p1p = p1p+1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                p1s = p1s+1;
            }           
        }

        if (p13c > 0)
        {
            if(p13c >1)
            {
                if(p13c > 2)
                {
                    if(p13c > 3)
                    {
                        p1f = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p1t = 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    p1p = p1p+1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                p1s = p1s+1;
            }

        }
        System.out.printf("p1s = %d",p1s);
        //System.out.printf("Player %d wins ", winner);
        //System.out.print("because %d beats %d\n",winCard, loseCard);  
    }

    public static char playAgain(){
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char cont = input.next().charAt(0);
        return cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your find winner method doesn't accept any parameters. Start by adding to variables to that method. For example `public static void findWinner(int p12c, int p13c)` etc.. Then when you call that method elsewhere in your code you use `findWinner(p12c, p13c);`

Comment: Don't declare the variables inside the void.  Declare them outside at the beginning of the class.  Alternately, use the results as return values.  You'd need to have variables to intercept those returns, but then they don't have to be global.

Comment: So if I declare the variables at the beginning of the class, it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field"

Comment: If you declare variables at the beginning of a class, they belong to an instance of that class.

You can make the members static, otherwise you'll need to create a new instance of the class with `new`

Comment: In Java, they're called methods

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables, you first have to have the variables being passed into the parameter:

```
public static void findWinner(int a, int b)  //Or how many ever variable you need
{
    ...
}
```

Then when you call that method, you need to pass in those variables:

```
int p12c = 1;
int p13c = 2;
findWinner(p12c, p13c);
```

---

On a side note, when you just want to increment the variable by one, you can do either of the following:

```
var x = 1;

x++;         // x = 2
x += 1;      // x = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put that variables that you need in to the brackets and remember that it is an local variables. In your method "findWinner" all that you need is hust wrote `public static void findWinner(int p12c, int p13c)` and all be Ok ;)